# compile only new code (C++)

Tags: c++, github, compilation

I downloaded the sourcecode of a big project from github. I want to learn a little bit more about c++ (and the project) by reading and playing around with some parts of the code.
"./configure" and "make" takes way to long for compilation.
How can I recompile without compilation of all files?
And what is the right way to work in such projects? Right now I compile through bash, I would really like to do everything from my normal c++ IDE (Clion).

Comment: `compile only new code` With a proper makefile, this should require no special actions. => Apparently, the makefile and/or your usage of it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `make` - it should process only changed files. Usually `configure` is needed to be executed only once to gather system configuration.

You can read in `make` man pages:

> `make`  updates  a target if it depends on prerequisite files that
>   have been modified since the target was last modified, or if the
>   target does not exist.